# how to use (.ssa) animation file in android

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I have a project implemented in iphone and i'm converting it to android , it has a lot of animation but i noticed that for each object animation there is (.ssa) file that use (.png) image to animate it ,, i couldn't open (.ssa) file and i need to use the same animation in android .. do you know what is (.ssa) file and how to use it in android or this way will not work and i need to implement the animation from scratch ?

Hint : (.png) image contains sequence of ordered images that (.ssa) file use it to make the animation ..

Comment: ssa is a subtitle format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha

Comment: yes i found this in first search but i found also something in ios called (Skeletal Animation) that animate images but not sure of that..